# Change value column header in TableView JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I am trying to create a TableView in JavaFX where the user can change the value of the column header by double clicking on the table header.
A Textbox should appear and after filling in a new value, the value should be assigned to the column header.

[Example of output below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVMvU.png)

Comment: Try the following approach: instead of setting the text on the column, set the graphic to a label. You can register a mouse listener with the label that changes the graphic to a text field on double-click, and register listeners with the text field that revert to the label when the user presses enter or when the text field loses focus. (The downside here is that it prohibits use of the table's built-in menu button.) Post a specific question if you have problems implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach than outlined in James' comment:

- register the mouse handler with the table
- on double-click (which interferes with sorting ... but that's a different problem), find the TableColumnHeader that represents the tableColumn, if any
- create and wire a TextField and set it as the column's graphic (as James suggested)

Note that the TableColumnHeader's package is version-dependent, for fx8 it's considered internal api residing in com.xx.skin, for fx9 it's public in javafx.xx.skin.

The example:

```
public class TableHeaderWithInput extends Application {
    TableView<Locale> table;

    protected void installHeaderHandler(Observable s) {
        table.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.isPrimaryButtonDown() &&  e.getClickCount() > 1) {
                EventTarget target = e.getTarget();
                TableColumnBase<?, ?> column = null;
                while (target instanceof Node) {
                    target = ((Node) target).getParent();
                    // beware: package of TableColumnHeader is version specific
                    if (target instanceof TableColumnHeader) {
                        column = ((TableColumnHeader) target).getTableColumn();
                        if (column != null) break;
                    }
                }
                if (column != null) {
                    TableColumnBase<?,?> tableColumn = column;
                    TextField textField = new TextField(column.getText());
                    textField.setMaxWidth(column.getWidth());
                    textField.setOnAction(a -> {
                        tableColumn.setText(textField.getText());
                        tableColumn.setGraphic(null);
                    });
                    textField.focusedProperty().addListener((src, ov, nv) -> {
                        if (!nv) tableColumn.setGraphic(null);
                    });
                    column.setGraphic(textField);
                    textField.requestFocus();
                }
                e.consume();
            }
        });
    }

    private Parent getContent() {
        table = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
        table.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);
        // quick hack: don't let sorting interfere ...
        table.setSortPolicy(e -> {return false;});
        TableColumn<Locale, String> countryCode = new TableColumn<>("CountryCode");
        countryCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("country"));
        TableColumn<Locale, String> language = new TableColumn<>("Language");
        language.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("language"));
        table.getColumns().addAll(countryCode, language);
        table.skinProperty().addListener(this::installHeaderHandler);
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(table);
        return pane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(getContent(), 800, 400));
        primaryStage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(TableHeaderWithInput.class.getName());
}
```